# How to make my custom tab component work with passing index to children and hiding panes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to create a custom Tabs component so I can learn react more, however I'm stuck.

There are three components and is inspired by Material-UI tabs. Tabs, Tab, and TabPane.

Tabs.js

```
const Tabs = (props) => {
    const { children, defaultTab } = props;
    const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(defaultTab);
    const onTabClick = (clickedTab = 0) => {
        setActiveTab(clickedTab);
    }
    return (
        <div className="tabs">
            {children}
        </div>
    )
}
```

This should hold the activeTab state and be able to tell Tab and TabPane of an active tab (or should it?).

Tab.js

```
const Tab = (props) => {
    const { label } = props;
    return (
        <li className="tabs-tab" onClick={  }> {label} </li>
    )
}

export default Tab;
```

The Tab component has `onClick` and a label. However, I'm not sure how to pass the function `onTabClick` from `Tabs` to this component via children.

```
TabPane.js
const TabPane = (props) => {
    const { children } = props;
    return (
        <div className="tabs-tab-pane">
            {children}
        </div>
    )
}

export default TabPane;
```

This is the container for content for each Tab. I'm not sure how to fetch the data in Tabs from here so I know when to hide the pane.

Here is a code share:

Here's a url to view this code and a preview: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-mendel-752qe?fontsize=14

How do I get this functional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this approach which relies on [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). Depending on your needs it *could* be simpler to put all the state in the top-level `App` and pass data via props but this approach will could offer more extensibility depending on your needs.

```js
const TabContext = React.createContext();

const Tabs = props => {
  const { children, defaultTab } = props;
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = React.useState(defaultTab);

  return (
    <TabContext.Provider value={{ activeTab, setActiveTab }}>
      {children}
    </TabContext.Provider>
  );
};

const Tab = props => {
  const { activeTab, setActiveTab } = React.useContext(TabContext);
  const { label, tabIndex } = props;
  const active = activeTab === tabIndex;

  return (
    <li
      onClick={() => setActiveTab(tabIndex)}
      className={`tabs-tab ${active ? "active" : ""}`}
    >
      {" "}
      {label}{" "}
    </li>
  );
};

const TabPane = props => {
  const { activeTab } = React.useContext(TabContext);
  const { children, tabIndex } = props;

  if (activeTab === tabIndex) {
    return <div className="tabs-tab-pane">{children}</div>;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Tabs defaultTab={0}>
        <div className="tabs">
          <Tab label="Home" tabIndex={0} />
          <Tab label="Contact" tabIndex={1} />
        </div>

        <TabPane tabIndex={0}>Tab Content for Home</TabPane>
        <TabPane tabIndex={1}>Tab Content for Contact</TabPane>
      </Tabs>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tabs {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 3px 0;
}

.tabs .tabs-tab {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabs .tabs-tab.active {
  background: orange;
}

.tabs .tabs-tab:hover {
  background: #777;
  color: #fff;
}

.tabs-tab-pane {
  padding: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks! This works great.

Is there any possible way TabsPane could work outside of <Tabs/>

Comment: You would have to put this context provider _above_ it in the tree. So you could put it out of `Tabs` or make a new component but it's one more component you have to remember to render.